# How to make CSV file as stream from ResultSet in Java?

Tags: java, ajax, scala, csv

I am making an ajax request to an endpoint to make `CSV` file from `ResultSet`. I am doing below code to do that.

```
 val statement = dbCon.createStatement()

      val rs = statement.executeQuery(exportQuery)

      val csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\wdd.csv"))

      val meta: ResultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData()
      val numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount()
      var dataHeaders = "\"" + meta.getColumnLabel(1) + "\""
      for (i <- 2 to numberOfColumns) {
        dataHeaders += ",\"" + meta.getColumnLabel(i) + "\""
      }
      csvWriter.println(dataHeaders)

      while (rs.next()) {
        var row = "\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\""
        for (i <- 2 to numberOfColumns) {
          row += ",\"" + rs.getString(i) + "\""
        }
        csvWriter.println(row)
      }
      csvWriter.close()
```

But the problem is that it is actually writing to a file in the server side. I don't want that to write a file in the server side instead i what i want is that when client will fire this endpoint, the file will automatically be downloaded in the client side.
This is my Ajax request.

```
exportDataAsCSVFile: function (schemaName, params) {
    var deferred = can.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/adhoc-matching/export-csv/' + schemaName,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, settings, exception) {
            deferred.reject(xhr, settings, exception);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

**How can i make CSV in memory as stream and send the stream to the client to automatically download as a file??**

I am using Scala **Ok(write(resp))** to send the response. **What needs to be changed to the request headers to send the stream?**

**EDIT:**

I could make the stream into an string. But what should i write in the ajax request to download the file in client side. I have tried to give dataType as "text/csv" or "text" and also added below headers.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 
        Accept : "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
    }
```

But the file is not downloading in the client side though the response has the text. **Below what i tried out to make CSV:**

```
val csvWriter: StringWriter = new StringWriter
    try {
      val statement = dbCon.createStatement()
      val rs = statement.executeQuery(exportQuery)
      val meta: ResultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData()
      val numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount()
      var dataHeaders = "\"" + meta.getColumnLabel(1) + "\""
      for (i <- 2 to numberOfColumns) {
        dataHeaders += ",\"" + meta.getColumnLabel(i) + "\""
      }
      csvWriter.write(dataHeaders + "\n")

      while (rs.next()) {
        var row = "\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\""
        for (i <- 2 to numberOfColumns) {
          row += ",\"" + rs.getString(i) + "\""
        }
        csvWriter.write(row + "\n")
        //csvWriter.println(row)
      }
      csvWriter.flush()
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
    }
    finally {
      dbCon.close()
      csvWriter.close()
    }
    val fileName = "untitled.csv"
    val csvData = csvWriter.toString
    Ok(csvData).as("text/csv; charset=utf-8").withHeaders(
      CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=$fileName",
      CONTENT_LENGTH -> csvData.length.toString
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code should look like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "csv",
      produces = { AdditionalMediaTypes.TEXT_CSV_UTF8, AdditionalMediaTypes.APPLICATION_CSV_UTF8 })
  public void getCsvFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    csvWriter.writeCsvToResponse(request, response);
  }
```

When called a csv file would download to the client.

```
  public void writeCsvToResponse(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  methodToWriteYourThingAsCsv.writeToStream(yourListOfObjectsYouWantToWrite, response.getOutputStream());
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to set anything in the headers. This is my form with which I download the csv:`<form method='get' acceptCharset='utf-8' action="ServerSideUrlToMyRestThatReturnsCsv>
        <button type='submit' onClick={event => { event.stopPropagation(); }}>
          Download
        </button>
      </form>);` You could first try to see the server side is working, by just calling it from the browser. It should download the csv, straight away. Now it's updated. I'm saying you don't need an ajax request for this.

Comment: can i do it using ajax request i showed in the code??

Comment: Now, I'm confused :) This is my understanding: you make the csv on the server side and you want it downloaded. First of all, if this is the way, you should change the ajax call to GET, from POST. It should work the way your ajax call is written.